# com.google.code.gson not getting resolved

Tags: json, gson, aem

I have included Google Gson dependency in the `pom.xml` of my project as shown below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm able to build the project without any issues but when I'm hitting the URL, the page doesn't load.

This is a CQ5 project and when I visit system/console to debug the issue, I find that the project package is not started.

Further, it gives the error: `com.google.gson,version=[2.2,3) -- Cannot be resolved`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Besides adding the dependency in pom.xml you have to install it in the OSGi container. You have 2 options:

**1. Include the JAR into your CQ package.**

All JARs put into CQ package folder `/jcr_root/apps/APP_NAME/install` [are installed automatically](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SlingHowToInstallBundlesViaJCRInstall.html) during CQ package installation. Therefore you can put the GSON library into this folder and it'll be added to the OSGi container.

If you are using assembly plugin to create CQ package, add following lines to the assembly descriptor:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/jcr_root/apps/YOUR_APP/install</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

It'll copy all dependencies with scope `runtime` to the `ouputDirectory`.

**2. Add the JAR as an embedded dependency in your bundle**

If you want to make the GSON available only for your bundle, but not for other bundles in the OSGi (eg. because there is already another version of GSON installed), you can embed the library. Use [`Embed-Dependency`](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#ApacheFelixMavenBundlePlugin%28BND%29-Embeddingdependencies) directive of the Maven bundle plugin, eg:

```
<Embed-Dependency>gson;scope=runtime</Embed-Dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to configure the  package plugin (where you configure the filters) in your package project. As stated in the [documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html#Embedding%20OSGi%20Bundles%20in%20a%20Content%20Package):

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>

            <embeddeds combine.children="append">
                    <embedded1>
                        <groupId>com.something.grouip</groupId>
                        <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>

                    </embedded1>

               </embeddeds>
            </configuration>
...
...
</plugin
```